# How can I allow users to distribute my Android app with their own preconfigured settings?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, customization

I have an Android app which other users would like to place on phones and give to colleagues/field workers.  For example, a supervisor may want this app on a hundred phones and give it to their field operatives or assistants.  They often need to preconfigure various settings for their own purposes.  They get the app itself from the Play Store.

Is there an 'Androidic' way I can allow the app to be generic but allow someone to preconfigure various preferences?

I am initially considering having the distributors place a 'settings' file somewhere on the phone; the app can check for the existence of this file and if it exists, read and apply settings from this file.

I don't know if it's possible to have the SharedPreference read+write from a text file instead of the built in mechanism so that it's more native.

Comment: How are you actually distributing the app? That, in turn, will tend to drive your options regarding this sort of pre-configuration.

Comment: Edited the post to mention that the app is on the Play Store.

Comment: "I don't know if it's possible to have the SharedPreference read+write from a text file instead of the built in mechanism so that it's more native" -- no, but you are welcome to read the "settings" file and apply it to your `SharedPreferences` as an import mechanism. There is no specific "Androidic" means for doing what you describe via the Play Store that I am aware of.